# Return list of points (x-y coordinates) that one point is connected to, and check against a separate status list

Tags: python

I have two tuples in Python "lines_origin" and "lines_dest" generated in a probably very inefficient way! But they show connections: lines_origin[1] is connected to lines_dest[2] and so on.

What I need to do, is iterate through a separate 'master' list of all possible coordinates individually, return the points its connected to, then check that sublist of connections against another list of statuses (on/off). Here's my attempt thus far:

```
import random
import numpy as np

### my list of all points
coordinates = []
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(20):
        coordinates.append((x,y))

### the connections between points
lines = []
while len(lines) < (800): # limiting each point to an average of 4 connections
    rnd_pair = random.sample(coordinates, 2)
    rnd_pair_rev = [rnd_pair[1],rnd_pair[0]]
    rnd_pair_x = [x for x,y in rnd_pair]
    rnd_pair_y = [y for x,y in rnd_pair]
    distance = abs(rnd_pair_x[0] - rnd_pair_x[1]) + abs(rnd_pair_y[0] - rnd_pair_y[1])
    if distance <=2:
        if rnd_pair not in lines and rnd_pair_rev not in lines:
            lines.append(rnd_pair)
    else:
        rnd_pair = []
        rnd_pair_rev = []
        rnd_pair_x = []
        rnd_pair_y = []

### splitting the connections into two tuples
lines_origin, lines_dest = zip(*lines)

### an array of binary statuses, these line up to coordinates by index (so if 
  # states[6] = "ON" then this denotes that coordinates[6] is on. 
states = np.random.choice(["ON", "OFF"], size = len(coordinates), replace=True, p=[0.2, 0.8])

### my failed attempt to iterate over the coordinates
for i in coordinates:
    if coordinates[i] in lines_origin:
        connections = lines_dest # this should return the coordinates of the points that coordinates[i] 
                                 # is connected to
    if coordinates[i] in lines_dest:
        connections.append(lines_origin) # as above but checking the destination points
    list(set(connections)) # dedupe the connections
    ### check whether a point is connected to an "ON" point
    for point in connections:
        return states[coordinates.index(connections[point])]
```

Comment: So in the last step you want to remove every connection from `lines_origin, lines_dest` where one or both coordinates are `OFF`. Am I Correct?

Comment: Not quite, its more a VLOOKUP type thing (apologies for the Excel reference). So the goal is to return the list of points that one point is connected to, and then find out which of those are on and which are off. Because that status will then lead to a new action (so if point is on, then "action a" happens to it, if point is off, then "action b" happens to it - these actions are yet to be coded, thats my next job).